# data.table's equivalent of dplyr's bang bang (!!)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Say I have this `DT` and `ID` below:

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
  ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
  a = 1:6,
  b = 7:12,
  c = 13:18
)

ID <- "b"
```

```r
DT
#>    ID a  b  c
#> 1:  b 1  7 13
#> 2:  b 2  8 14
#> 3:  b 3  9 15
#> 4:  a 4 10 16
#> 5:  a 5 11 17
#> 6:  c 6 12 18
```

Is there a `{data.table}` equivalent of `{dplyr}`'s:

```r
DT |> dplyr::filter(ID == !!ID)
#>    ID a b  c
#> 1:  b 1 7 13
#> 2:  b 2 8 14
#> 3:  b 3 9 15
```

Assuming I don't change the variable's name.

Comment: Why not simply change the variable name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just wrap the variable in `as.name()`:

```
DT[ID == as.name(ID)]

#    ID a b  c
# 1:  b 1 7 13
# 2:  b 2 8 14
# 3:  b 3 9 15
```

Answer (score 3):

I like that VitaminB16's answer works in the `i=` (as well as `j=`) portions of `data.table::[`. However, I believe the *canonical* response to referencing an object from the calling environment is the `..`-operator, discussed here: https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-intro.html

Unfortunately, it does not work in `i=`,

```r
DT[ID == ..ID,]
# Error in eval(stub[[3L]], x, enclos) : object '..ID' not found
```

So must be placed in a `.SD`. (I believe this works in `.SD`'s `i=` because it is initially evaluated in the `DT`'s `j=` ... perhaps convoluted.)

```r
DT[, .SD[ID == ..ID,] ]
#        ID     a     b     c
#    <char> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:      b     1     7    13
# 2:      b     2     8    14
# 3:      b     3     9    15
```

Comment: 2nd row now shows col classes, is it new version of DT?

Comment: This was added in 1.13.0 with [833702a](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/833702aa7049c38b0c3abf554d00b1cde80bb0db), with an argument `print.data.table(..., class=TRUE)` or `options(datatable.print.class=TRUE)`. I tend to now read the more mundane function docs very often, but this is listed in `?print.data.table` :-)

Comment: Edit: I tend to ***not*** read the more mundane function docs very often ...